# C++: grpc send data with proto defined on runtime

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, grpc, proto, protobuf-c

I have the need to define proto fields of a message on runtime and send data along with them. So what I've done is I've defined them on runtime using `FieldDescriptorProto` and send it from server to client.

My proto file looks like this:

```
syntax = "proto3";

import "google/protobuf/descriptor.proto";

package handshake;

option cc_enable_arenas = true;

message ProtoRequest {
    google.protobuf.FileDescriptorProto custom_proto = 1;
}

service HandShake {    
    rpc sendProto (ProtoRequest) returns (ProtoResponse) {}
}

message ProtoResponse {
    bool received = 1;
}
```

what I did is I defined the fields and set values to them in the server-side, something like this:

```
// --- server ---

// assume all fields are int64
const google::protobuf::Message* message = factory.GetPrototype(message_desc);
google::protobuf::Message* mutable_msg = message->New(&arena);

const Reflection* reflection = mutable_msg->GetReflection();
const Descriptor* descriptor = mutable_msg->GetDescriptor();

for (int i = 0; i < descriptor->field_count(); i++) {
    const FieldDescriptor * fd = descriptor->field(i);
    reflection->SetInt64(mutable_msg,fd,i);
}

// verification
for (int i = 0; i < descriptor->field_count(); i++) {
    const FieldDescriptor* fd = descriptor->field(i);
    // reflection->SetInt64(mutable_msg, fd, i);
    cout << fd->name() << " -> " << reflection->GetInt64(*mutable_msg, fd) << endl;
}
```

I verify if the values are set on the server-side and it was good. But When I transfer the `FileDescriptor` to the client:

```
// --- client ---

FileDescriptorProto local_proto = request->custom_proto(); //this is from the server

//const google::protobuf::Descriptor* message_desc = local_proto.GetDescriptor();

DescriptorPool pool_;
const FileDescriptor* local_proto_;
local_proto_ = pool_.BuildFile(local_proto);

// display message contents
const google::protobuf::Descriptor* message_desc = local_proto_->FindMessageTypeByName("AttribRow");
cout << "Field Count: " << message_desc->field_count() << endl;

google::protobuf::DynamicMessageFactory factory;
const google::protobuf::Message* mutable_msg = factory.GetPrototype(message_desc);

const Reflection* reflection = mutable_msg->GetReflection();
const Descriptor* descriptor = mutable_msg->GetDescriptor();

for (int i = 0; i < descriptor->field_count(); i++) {
    const FieldDescriptor* fd = descriptor->field(i);
    cout << fd->name() << " -> " << reflection->GetInt64(*mutable_msg, fd) << endl; //this fails
}
```

When I verify if I received the data successfully on the client side, all the fields are set to 0 (default value of the datatype).

So what I need in simple words is, I want to transfer data as protobuf, whose field names I know only at runtime. So I should be defining proto fields for those and transfer data along with them from server to client successfully.

Comment: First thing I would do is look at the actual protobuf sent (and received) and make sure your fields w/values are in there.  (Remembering of course that the protobuf has no field names, only field numbers.)  To be more precise: Look at the actual protobuf to see what's in there at all (maybe the field #s aren't what you think).  Interesting question - I had no idea this capability existed.

Comment: What is the value of `descriptor->field_count()` on client-side?

Comment: @Azeem 114 and it is exact . I have no problems with that

Comment: @DeepakGurumoorthy: And, the serialized message is of the same size as well (in bytes at sending and receiving ends)?

Comment: @DeepakGurumoorthy I suspect the issue has to do with how the proto is being serialized and deserialized. For debugging purposes, I would suggest trying to locally serialize, deserialize and then verify if the contents are the same.